# ListBox for Extjs example?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs7

i trying to find some way to display/insert/update the information on the form where the information is dynamic. the extjs i currently using is **Ext JS 7.1.x Classic**

the schema are as below
name of item
cost price of the item
product code of the item
location ([latitude and longitude];rack number;shelves number)
remarks

For example the forms will have a list of location in the form for that item which i able to to add, delete and update each row of location?

data are as show below

1. PowerBank,10,MPB001,["000.1,111";2;2,"000.2,222";2;2,"000.1,111";1;2],My Power Bank
2. Earphone,4,MEP001,["000.1,111";2;3],My Earphone

i thinking of something like ListView or Datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

For initial data, update data and insert you can use

```
form.setValues({
    name: 'PowerBank',
    cost: 10,
    code: 'MPB001',
    locationLatitude: '000.1',
    locationLongitude: '111'
    rack: 2,
    shelves: 2,
    remarks: 'My Power Bank'
});
```

Other than that you could use data-binding

**data-binding**

Let's say you have a grid and bind the selection:

```
xtype: 'grid',
bind: {selection: '{gridSelection}'}
```

And you have the selected dataset in your viewModel

```
data: {
    gridSelection: null
}
```

Then you can add the data to the form like this:

```
items: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'remarks',
    bind: {value: '{gridSelection.remarks}'}
}
```

*problem*
you might run into a problem if you are trying to listen on the dirty states with data-binding. But you can solve this by making all fields not dirty after the data-binding triggers.